# WhatsApp chat no backing up on iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

My WhatsApp chat history won’t back up on my iPhone 12/iCloud account. When I try to do so it says I don’t have enough storage and I need to free up 8GB, despite the fact that I have an 2TB iCloud account (and that I’m using only 288 GB of that 2TB). The capacity on my iPhone itself is pretty small (less than 6GB left out of 64GB), so I’d really like to be able to use my iCloud storage for my WhatsApp chats instead of my actual iPhone storage. Does anyone know what I can do? Thanks!

EDIT: Thank you both for your replies. I wasn't aware that WhatsApp requires 2.05 times as much space on both the phone AND iCloud to enable the backup. I have enough space on iCloud but not the phone, sadly. As for the other question/comment, I have added the picture. However, I am afraid I am not sure what the difference between backing up and offloading is. In short, I would like to keep a backup of my conversations in case I lose my phone and want to use another one.

If anyone has any tips (other than increasing my phone storage, which is sadly not possible), I would be much grateful. Thanks again for your help.

[image]

Comment: https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/chats/how-to-back-up-to-icloud/?lang=en says you need 2.05 times as much space on both phone & cloud to enable the backup. Can't test, don't have WhatsApp, but it might be that it's the phone that doesn't have enough space.

Comment: Are you talking about backups or about offloading part of your chat history?

Comment: Also, if you included an image in your question it somehow didn't work.